# Code crashing when trying to create PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, wpf, principal

Whenever I make a call to this method, I crash.

```
    public bool findSAMAccountByName(string environmentUserName)
    {
        try
        {
            const string Domain = "someserver";
            // set up domain context
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain);

            // find a user
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, environmentUserName);

            if (user != null)
            {
                // do something here....     
                string samAccountName = user.SamAccountName;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.ToString();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The innerexception says

> {"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt."}

StackTrace is

```
 at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.GetEx(String bstrName, Object& value)
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, String identityValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, String identityValue)
   at ActiveRecord.MainWindow.findSAMAccountByName(String environmentUserName) in MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 60
   at ActiveRecord.MainWindow..ctor() in MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 39
```

---

My call to this method is causing the crash

```
                if (findSAMAccountByName(Environment.UserName))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Username found");
                }
```

If I remove/comment the code, it compiles and runs fine.

---

### UPDATE: After following  DJ KRAZE's advice

```
const string Domain = "someserver";
```

After changing the PrincipalContext to accept 2 agruements, the new StackTrace is

```
      at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
```

Comment: on which line exception is thrown?

Comment: My call to this method

                    if (findSAMAccountByName(Environment.UserName))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Username found");
                    }

Comment: in which specific line inside findSAMAccountByName function? please run in debug mode...

Comment: you could replace the if statement and try something like this `UserPrincipal foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, IdentityType.Name, username);`

Comment: What does your `Domain and DC=` look like..?

Comment: I am running in Debug mode

Comment: DC= is part of the connection string to your AD environment nothing to do with Debug mode Cocoa Dev.. ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocoa Dev something like this should work..

```
const string Domain = "SomeServer.Foo.Bar.com";
const string Username = "someUserSamAccountName";

PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain);
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext,  Username);
```

replace with your values and this should return if a user is found or not.. I work with AD on a daily basis and just tested with my account creds hope this helps if so change your Method to pass in  string samAccount , string DomanName;

hard coded example that you can follow

```
const string Domain = "SLO1.Foo.Bar.biz:389";
const string Container = @"DC=Foo,DC=Bar,DC=biz";
const string Username = @"cocoadev";//replace with actual samAccountName
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain, Container);
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext,  username);
```

Comment: The stacktrace changed but InnerException is the same.

Comment: Cocoa Dev, does that code work for you if so update the comment or delete it.. so it does not cause confusion also please place what your DC=Looks like so I can provide you a solution that works I helped an OP last week with the same issue ..thanks

Comment: Do I need to have the fully qualified domain as part of the server or just the server name?

Comment: I will post an example that will give you an Idea and just follow the pattern but replace it with your own values ok

Comment: Adding the container actually stopped the problem.

Comment: That's what I was trying to have you show me earlier when I asked about what your `DC=` looks like.. glad I was able to provide you with a working solution